# Check if a column value conforms to a specific sql data type in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a sql table with column type set as varbinary. I will insert data from comma delimited file. Then after insertion, i will check if some specific column values are in specific sql type in run time and generate report to view in winforms. column names and data type will be selected by user from combobox and the application will filter the rows which have those columns compatible with those specific types and generate report to show in listview.

I am using sql server 2008.
I am using also Dapper in my application.

I am not sure whether i have to check it in sql query. If in sql query then what should be the where clause?

I have got stuck with this. So, I beg your help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code what you have tried.

Comment: I have just tried to check if a column contains null or empty value with DATALENGTH(columnname)>0 in where clause. I can't figure out how should i check column values to specific sql types where in table column properties are varbinary and in model class have all properties as string.

Comment: Why `varbinary` if the models are `string`? And are all of the columns of the CSV being put in the same `varbinary` column?

Comment: The table contains 206 columns. All data are exported from other system as comma delimited file and my application imports data from file and then generates report for rows with specific columns empty or rows with specific columns for specific data types. Probably nvarchar or varchar in table column data types should be ok too. The reason is that user wants that any column may have any type of valid or invalid data, but upload should not fail. after upload i have to filter rows to generate report.